# UICollectionView not responding to UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, api, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have created a UICollectionView containing data from an API, which displays titles and poster images. The UICollection works fine showing both correctly.

I am trying to implement a UISearchBar that searches based on the title. The issue I am having is the UICollectionView does not respond or update when using the UISearchBar.

Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking

class FilmsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, 
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, 
UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

var films: [NSDictionary]?
var filteredFilms: [NSDictionary]?
var searching:Bool = false



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    filmsTable.dataSource = self
    filmsTable.delegate = self

    loadFilms()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}

//SEARCH BAR

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    self.filteredFilms?.removeAll()
    if searchText != "" {
        searching = true
        for film in self.films! {
            if (film["title"] as! String).contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                self.filteredFilms?.insert(film, at: (filteredFilms?.endIndex)!)
            }
        }
    } else {
        searching = false 
        self.filteredFilms = self.films
    }

    filmsTable.reloadData()
}

/*
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    let search = searchBar.text!

    if search.isEmpty {
        self.filmsTable.reloadData()
    }
    else {

        // let search = searchBar.text!

        filteredFilms = films!.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

            //Access the title and sectors
            let filmTitle = text["title"] as! NSString

            //Create a range for both
            let range1 = filmTitle.range(of: search, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

            self.filmsTable.reloadData()
            return range1 != nil

        })

        self.filmsTable.reloadData()

    }

}

*/

//Collection View Layout

func collectionView(_ _collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searching {
        return filteredFilms?.count ?? 0
    } else {
        return films?.count ?? 0
    }
}




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = filmsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "filmCell", for: indexPath) as! FilmCell

        if searching {
            let film = filteredFilms![indexPath.row]
            let title = film["title"] as! String
            cell.titleLabel.text = title

        } else {
            let film = films![indexPath.row]
            let title = film["title"] as! String

            cell.titleLabel.text = title

        }

        return cell
    }

    //End Collection View Layout

    //Parse Film API

    func loadFilms() {

        let apiKey = ""
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)&language=en-US&page=1")
        let request = URLRequest(
            url: url! as URL,
            cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 10 )

        let session = URLSession (
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            delegate: nil,
            delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main
        )

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (dataOrNil, response, error) in
            if let data = dataOrNil {
                if let resposeDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? NSDictionary {

                    self.films = resposeDictionary["results"] as? [NSDictionary]
                    print("response: \(resposeDictionary)")
                }

            }

            self.filteredFilms = self.films
            self.filmsTable.reloadData()

        })

        task.resume()

    }

    //End Parse Film API



}
```

EDIT: I've also tried this. I get error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSDictionary]' with an index of type 'String' at the "filmTable =" line.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text ==  "" {
        searching = false
        filmsTable.reloadData()
    } else {
        searching = true
        let filmTitle = films!["title"] as! NSString
        filteredFilms = films!.filter({$0.filmTitle.range(of: searchBar.text!) != nil})
        filmsTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: self.filteredFilms?.insert(film, at: (filteredFilms?.endIndex)!)  why not use append(film).

Comment: I don’t see you setting your “searching” variable to true anywhere. So you are basically using the films array all the time to populate the table

Comment: @E.Coms I used what was in the notes originally. It would collect the titles from the NSDictionary and print displays the list of titles. Then I would find the range. Problem is the UIController would not display the search results. So I also tried the insert method and they're still not displaying.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla I have updated the code with searching = true where needed. CollectionView will still not display results.

Comment: You should use  self.filteredFilms?.append(film) . The insertion has a problem .  In your original way, you cannot  run "self.filmsTable.reloadData()" when do the filtration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where exactly in your code you are having trouble. However, I can give you a few suggestions and a working example of what you are trying to do.

1. If you are trying to populate a collectionView using an array always declare the arrays as empty arrays (in case you need it empty) instead of optionals.
2. If you don't need a boolean, don't use it - in your case the searching boolean is not needed to be honest.
3. Simplify as much as possible your code. In your case, the filter function will give you a filtered array - So no need to insert or append items in the filteredFilms array.

Here is a working example of what you want to do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    var films = [["title" : "one"], ["title" : "two"], ["title" : "three"]]
    var filteredFilms = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

    let searchBar = UISearchBar()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.searchBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.filteredFilms = films
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredFilms.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText == "" {
            self.filteredFilms = films
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.filteredFilms = films.filter({($0["title"]?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))!})
            print(self.filteredFilms.count)
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

class Cell : UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: The UICollectionView is now reloading and showing search results. The number of results are showing in console. Only problem now is a strange one. Say I am searching for the film "Venom". If I search "Ve" nothing will appear but if I search "nom" the cell will appear. It shows results for strings of letters in the middle or end of title but not if it's the full title. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually it is because the first letter is a capital. So I will have to lowercase what the search is looking for. The search is searching for venom when its Venom. How would I lowercase the title text not just the search text?

Comment: Yes, just add this. self.filteredFilms = films.filter({($0["title"]?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!}).    If it helped please accept the answer

Comment: I got an error on your original code until it was turned into this. "self.filteredFilms = films!.filter({(($0["title"] as AnyObject).contains(searchText.lowercased()))})". If I add .lowercased after "AnyObject) I get an error: "Cannot invoke 'lowercased' with no arguments"

Comment: Why do you have to use AnyObject? Just cast it to String instead of AnyObject - as String?. And one last suggestion. NEVER EVER show your API keys in a public forum

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to do is:

```
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.filteredFilms?.removeAll()
    if searchText != "" {
        searching = true
        for film in self.films! {
            if (film["title"] as! String).contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                self.filteredFilms?.insert(film, at: (filteredFilms?.endIndex)!)
            }
        }
    } else {
        searching = false
        self.filteredFilms = self.films
    }

    filmsTable.reloadData()
}
```

UISearchBarDelegate:  `(_ searchBar:...` not `(searchBar:...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this hopefully it will work:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text ==  "" {
        searching = false
        filmsTable.reloadData()
    } else {
        searching = true
        filteredFilms = films.filter({$0.["title"].range(of: searchBar.text!) != nil})
        filmsTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: It errors with "Expected member name following '.'"